# create a variable based on ordered and grouped values of two other columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, data-analysis

I have a table like the following one in R :

| team | tournament | pool | year | sets ratio | points ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| team 1 | tournament 1 | a | 2011 | 3.00 | 0.89 |
| team 2 | tournament 1 | a | 2011 | 1.00 | 1.57 |
| team 3 | tournament 1 | a | 2011 | 1.50 | 1.11 |
| team 4 | tournament 1 | b | 2011 | 1.33 | 1.05 |

I would like to create a new column (final_standing) that gives the final standing for each team in each pool (basically grouping by pool, year, and tournament).

final standing follows two criteria:

1. sets ratio
2. points ratio (in case set ratio is equal)

I have tried something like:

```
library(dplyr)

data = data %>% 
  group_by(pool, year, tournament) %>% 
  mutate(pool_position = order(sets ratio, points ratio, runif(sets ratio), decreasing = TRUE))
```

but it does not give what I was expecting.

They also suggested me this:

```
 tmp <- aggregate(list(a = data$sets_ratio, b = data$points_ratio), list(p = data$pool, y = data$year, t = data$tournament), function(x) sort(-x))
    m <- match(paste0(data$pool, data$year, data$tournament), paste0(tmp$p, tmp$y, tmp$t))
    df[,c(“sets_rk”, “points_rk”)] <- tmp[m,c(4:5)]
```

But it returns sets and points rankings separately. In contrast, I want a unique variable that evaluates first the sets ratio and then the points ratio if the sets ratio between the two teams is equal.

Comment: What *were* you expecting?

Comment: create a variable that ranks teams in each pool, for each tournament, and year according to sets and points ratios.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to create a tie with regard to `sets.ratio` in your sample data. `final_standing` is coded in such a way that a higher ratio results in a higher `final_standing`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
     ~team,    ~tournament, ~pool, ~year, ~sets.ratio, ~points.ratio,
  "team 1", "tournament 1",   "a", 2011L,           3,          0.89,
  "team 3", "tournament 1",   "a", 2011L,         1.5,          1.11,
  "team 2", "tournament 1",   "a", 2011L,         1.5,          1.57,
  "team 4", "tournament 1",   "b", 2011L,        1.33,          1.05
  )


df |> 
  mutate(final_standing = row_number(pick(sets.ratio, points.ratio)),
         .by = c(year, tournament, pool))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#>   team   tournament   pool   year sets.ratio points.ratio final_standing
#>   <chr>  <chr>        <chr> <int>      <dbl>        <dbl>          <int>
#> 1 team 1 tournament 1 a      2011       3            0.89              3
#> 2 team 3 tournament 1 a      2011       1.5          1.11              1
#> 3 team 2 tournament 1 a      2011       1.5          1.57              2
#> 4 team 4 tournament 1 b      2011       1.33         1.05              1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>